# How do I check for syntax errors in my java.security configuration file

Tags: java, java-security

Is there any way to check configuration file before using it, for example for Apache web server "apache2ctl configtest" command checking file syntax.

Comment: Please explain why you would like to do that. Already sounds fishy to me

Comment: In my product customer can disable TLSv1 and TLSv1.1 manually in java.security file if he/she want to. So after that I want to check the file to understand syntax correct or not.